# Send TCP message at random time to one of several clients in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, tcp

I am trying to send a TCP message at random time, depending on when the user input is received, to one of several clients from which I am receiving data on a thread for each client.

I am storing the IP of each client inside an SQL database and I decide to which IP i want to send data based on user input. How should I approach sending a message to a specific client ? I don't know how I can gain access over each socket connection and use it to send messages.

Any device, links of examples, or code snippets are greatly welcome.

This is the server code that I have so far :

```
import socket
import threading
from database import Database

d = Database()
def Read_RFID_tag():
    while True:
        receiveID = raw_input("tag input : ")
        d.updateTable(receiveID, 1);
        print(receiveID)

class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            print("new client")
            client.settimeout(60)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        while True:
            query_result = d.existsWashedInTable(address)
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    # Set the response to echo back the received data
                    print(data)
                    response = data
                    d.addEntryToTable(response,address, 0)
                    client.send(response)
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port_num = 5005
    d.createTable()
    threading.Thread(target=Read_RFID_tag).start()
    ThreadedServer('',port_num).listen()
```

Comment: Create a list, eg `self.clients = []` and store your clients there.

Comment: Thank you, @t.m.adam, this solved my problem.